# Advanced RecyclerView library - code examples

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, swipe, dismiss

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

This seems to be a great library in terms of what functionality it offers. However, it lacks good documentation. It has a "tutorial" on `Swipeable` items, but like some other people I couldn't follow it.

Does anyone have a working example or can anyone make a simple Use Case of swiping an item and showing a button under it using this library? It would be useful for lots of people interested in this functionality.

Comment: I cant find any documentation when i've added the dependency to the project. It says very well what it can do using the example app but when it comes to using it... Im lost. Hope you find someone who knows more about this library i'm about to try alternatives :/

Comment: There is [an alternative](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/wiki) with somewhat better documentation.

Comment: Wow I think this might be the answer to my questions and desires! Seems greatly documented as well but I'm yet to look at it. Thank you very much. If you'd like, make your comment an answer.

Comment: If swiping or dragging is what you want you can easily implement it yourself with ItemTouchHelper and RecyclerView with out needing to add a library as a dependancy, refer to here for a tutorial: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.x8ka8qcw7 Then as far as a button underneath goes you just have to limit the swipe animation to go far enough to expose your button and handle the click for it. Theres a 2nd part to the above tutorial which contains a section for custom swipe animations https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd

Answer (score 3):

You can find better detailed documentation in the main website:
https://advancedrecyclerview.h6ah4i.com

and the following is copied from the [swipeable](https://advancedrecyclerview.h6ah4i.com/swipeable/) page in the documentation:

---

**Step 1. Make the adapter supports stable IDs**

This step is very important. If adapter does not return stable & unique IDs, that will cause some weird behaviors (wrong animations, NPE, etc...)

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    MyAdapter() {
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // requires static value, it means need to keep the same value
        // even if the item position has been changed.
        return mItems.get(position).getId();
    }
}
```

---

**Step 2. Modify layout file of item views**

Wrap content views with another `FrameLayout` whitch has `@+id/container` ID.

```
<!-- for itemView -->
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp">
    <!-- Content View(s) -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

⏬   ⏬   ⏬

```
<!-- for itemView -->
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp">

    <!-- for getSwipeableContainerView() -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Content View(s) -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

---

**Step 3. Modify `ViewHolder`**

1. Change parent class to `AbstractSwipeableItemViewHolder`.
2. Implement `getSwipeableContainerView()` method.

> Note: The `AbstractSwipeableItemViewHolder` class is a convenience class which implements boilerplace methods of `SwipeableItemViewHolder.

```
class MyAdapter ... {
    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

⏬   ⏬   ⏬

```
class MyAdapter ... {
    static class MyViewHolder extends AbstractSwipeableItemViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        FrameLayout containerView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            containerView = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        }

        @Override
        public View getSwipeableContainerView() {
            return containerView;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Step 4. Implement the `SwipeableItemAdapter` interface**

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ...
}
```

⏬   ⏬   ⏬

```
class MyAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>
        implements SwipeableItemAdapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public int onGetSwipeReactionType(MyViewHolder holder, int position, int x, int y) {
        // Make swipeable to LEFT direction
        return Swipeable.REACTION_CAN_SWIPE_LEFT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSetSwipeBackground(MyViewHolder holder, int position, int type) {
        // You can set background color/resource to holder.itemView.

        // The argument "type" can be one of the followings;
        // - Swipeable.DRAWABLE_SWIPE_NEUTRAL_BACKGROUND
        // - Swipeable.DRAWABLE_SWIPE_LEFT_BACKGROUND
        // (- Swipeable.DRAWABLE_SWIPE_UP_BACKGROUND)
        // (- Swipeable.DRAWABLE_SWIPE_RIGHT_BACKGROUND)
        // (- Swipeable.DRAWABLE_SWIPE_DOWN_BACKGROUND)

        if (type == Swipeable.DRAWABLE_SWIPE_LEFT_BACKGROUND) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SwipeResultAction onSwipeItem(MyViewHolder holder, int position, int result) {
        // Return sub class of the SwipeResultAction.
        //
        // Available base (abstract) classes are;
        // - SwipeResultActionDefault
        // - SwipeResultActionMoveToSwipedDirection
        // - SwipeResultActionRemoveItem
        // - SwipeResultActionDoNothing

        // The argument "result" can be one of the followings;
        // 
        // - Swipeable.RESULT_CANCELED
        // - Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_LEFT
        // (- Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_UP)
        // (- Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_RIGHT)
        // (- Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_DOWN)

        if (result == Swipeable.RESULT_LEFT) {
            return new SwipeResultActionMoveToSwipedDirection() {
                // Optionally, you can override these three methods
                // - void onPerformAction()
                // - void onSlideAnimationEnd()
                // - void onCleanUp()
            };
        } else {
            return new SwipeResultActionDoNothing();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Step 5. Modify initialization process of `RecyclerView`**

Put some additional initialization process in your `Activity` / `Fragment`.

1. Instantiate `RecyclerViewSwipeManager`.
2. Create a wrapped adapter and set it to `RecyclerView`.
3. Attach `RecyclerView` to `RecyclerViewSwipeManager`.

---

```
void onCreate() {
    ...

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

⏬   ⏬   ⏬

```
void onCreate() {
    ...

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerViewSwipeManager swipeManager = new RecyclerViewSwipeManager();

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
    RecyclerView.Adapter wrappedAdapter = swipeManager.createWrappedAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // disable change animations
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    swipeManager.attachRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

---

I hope my answer will help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16457078)

Comment: @Dev-iL can you please change the review now ?

Comment: Hi @Zacktamondo, I'm not sure what you mean - the review refers to a previous version of the post, so everybody who comes across it will see that the post was edited _afterwards_ - which is the intended outcome of a review comment. I didn't give you a -1 on this, and regardless, seeing how you're a new user and your behavior is encouraged on SO (i.e. responding to a review by editing your post) - you can have my +1 :)

Comment: @Dev-iL thank you
do you recommend me to delete and re-post the answer?

Comment: Please don't do that. You have a +1/-1 on this answer, which means you are at a net positive rep gain. Deleting the answer will only hurt you, but more importantly - reposting the same thing is frowned upon on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I found the library to be well documented and easy to use.

I have picked the code from the original sample that was needed to implement swipe with button underneath which can be found [here](https://github.com/AnirudhaAgashe/android-advancedrecyclerview-swipe-sample).

Hopefully following tips will make it even more easier to understand the pattern in which samples are implemented.

**Overview**

`createAdapter` method in [LauncherPageFragment](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/launcher/LauncherPageFragment.java)
gives a overview as to which activity contains which feature

Every sample follow either of the the two pattern:

**Basic Sample**
In case of basic sample the adapter and view holder needed for the recycler view are defined in the same activity class.

**Complex Sample**
In case of complex sample the adapter and view holder are created separately and the recycler view is itself defined in another fragment.
In such cases there is a additional fragment which is added in activity. These are present in `com.h6ah4i.android.example.advrecyclerview.common.fragment` package, which is used to provide the data that needs to be displayed in the recycler view.

For the swipe with button you need to create
`RecyclerViewTouchActionGuardManager` (to suppress scrolling while swipe-dismiss animation is running) and `RecyclerViewSwipeManager` to create a wrapped adapter.

For adapater you will need to implment `SwipeableItemAdapter` interface and view holder needs to extend `AbstractSwipeableItemViewHolder` instead of RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

**Note:**
I have changed implementation of `onSetSwipeBackground`
In original sample it set some background on the itemview.
This was not needed in case where the view underneath is to be shown. Also it was causing unnecessary redraws.